# Create dummy data with Tinker/Laravel

Tags: laravel, tinker

In Tinker, `App\Models\Project::all();` returns a list of all projects. Now I would like to add additional dummy data with `factory(App\Models\Project::class, 10)->create();`, but nothing is happening.

What am I doing wrong and how could I debug it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `database/factories/ModelFactory.php` you have to make sure you define a Model Factory for your Project Model:

```php
$factory->define(App\Project::class, function (Faker\Generator $faker) {
    return [
        'name' => $faker->sentence,
    ];
});
```

You'll see one in there for the User Model already.
https://laravel.com/docs/database-testing#writing-factories